# how to populate the join table with the create method in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, many-to-many

I'm trying to populate the join-table with the id's from two other tables, adding the user id is relatively easy because of devise but the other Id is giving me issues in the create method.

The UserItems table holds its id the user_id and the item_id, its the link between the two tables allowing for a many-to-many relationship.

here is the code

```
def create
  @user_item = UserItem.new(user_item_params)
  @user_item.user_id = current_user.id
  @user_item.item = Item.find(params[:item_id])


  if @user_item.save
    redirect_to @user_item, notice: 'successfully created.'        
  else
    render action: 'new'         
  end    
end
```

user_item_params is a method in the user_items_controller.rb as well

```
def user_item_params
  params.require(:user_item).permit(:item_id, :user_id)
end
```

This line

```
  @user_item.item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
```

is the line I think I have wrong, I don't think its populating the table with the right item id.

I'm doing this through test driven development, the test that is currently failing is supposed to get a 404 if a user or item does not exist for a given user_item. Since 404 is rendered automatically when these items are not found adding these lines of code should fix that. But they aren't.

I have the correct relationships set up in the code, I didn't want to clutter the question with the full controller.

As always any help is very much appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: Where do you set your `@item` variable?

Comment: Thats the problem, I don't have a @item set here I tried `@item = Item.find(params[:id])` but that didn't work, I thought I would leave the code that I put up here in its simplest broken form.

Answer (score 0):

You've not shown us any error message or demonstrated what isn't working, but theres a number salient points that jump out from the code.

1. You don't often update the join table directly, usually you'd do something like `current_user.items << @item`
2. You don't appear to be initialising `@item` anywhere
3. If you're creating a new `UserItem` with `user_item_params`, you ought not need to then manually assign the attributes if your params are correct

What would be really useful is to know what exactly your `params` hash looks like, to get an idea of what you're actually POSTing.

Comment: edited question to try and make it clearer. thanks for the input.

Comment: You seem to be just guessing at what to do, don't code by guessing. Inspect the parameters you're receiving at your controller, are you getting an ID for an Item object? if so, what is the parameter called? What the URL that your form POSTs to? etc

Answer (score 0):

you can use if you have a model named Item and if you define the association

```
@user_item.item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
```

otherwise

```
@user_item.item_id = Item.find(params[:item_id]).id
```

Comment: I have tested both of these but neither of them work in my code.
My test cases still fail.

Comment: is this problem specific with test cases or while running the code

Comment: its specific to test cases, I havn't ran the code at all since I know it will fail. I'm using Rspec to test and develop the whole application.

Comment: i think You are not having any record for Item with id = params[:itme_id]. check in test cases by finding the Item with the item_id you are sending to controller